# Proving that if $g(x)$ is injective, and $g(f(x))$ is injective, then $f(x)$ is injective

Tags: functions

Conjecture: If $g(x)$ is injective, and $g(f(x))$ is injective, then $f(x)$ is injective

How can I prove that conjecture formally?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should specify domains and codomains of f and g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(a)=f(b)$. Hence $g(f(a))=g(f(b))$. Since $gf$ is injective. Therefore $a=b$

Comment: Very nice Amr. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I didnt see that

Comment: Note that this works even if $g$ is not assumed to be injective.

Comment: @pie you can [accept](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3287/8271) this answer.

Comment: On another glace, I don't understands how you reached the conclusion a=b... can you explain please? Because if f(x)=x^2, then  f(a)=f(b) (for instance a=2 and b=-2) and g(f(a))=g(f(b)) but b=/=a. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: If $f(x)=x^2$, then $g\circ f$ will not be injective (on $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: sorry then I don't understand why since  g∘f is injective, a=b.